# "You have nowhere to store this vehicle"

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I play as Michael and removed a car from the garage by driving out (garage is now empty). When I try to order a car through the internet, it says "you have nowhere to store this vehicle". Why? My garage is empty now. Do I need a extra garage for a racecar?

Comment: Are you talking about his safehouse garage?

Comment: @Josh: Hm not sure about the name, but the garage in his village is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the answer to this question about garages: [How does the garage system work in GTA V?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131250/how-does-the-garage-system-work-in-gta-v/131283#131283)

> Taken from the manual:
>   Player characters can own any vehicle in [GTA V] as long they have appropriate storage for it. To purchase a new car they must first own a garage ...

So yes, you must purchase another garage.